# Email notifications please

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Why are there no email notifications when answers or comments are added to your question?

I don't spend all day on SF so it would be great to receive an email to notify me that an update has been posted?

Comment: Jacques - from the questions you've asked on SF, it seems that you're not an IT admin. Is that the case?

Answer (score 13):

Did you provide an email address when you posted your question ? Click on the link

[image: Clicky linky thing]

Then fill in the email address and click save

[image: demo email]

**As an aside, if you've asked a question you really ought to do us the courtesy of checking in occasionally, after all it's in your interest to do so.**

Comment: +1 on the checking in.. Who are going to answer questions if everyone just wants answers on their own questions?

Comment: +1 for checking in. Stack Exchange is not a magical free answer machine: it only works because of user participation and [the pay it forward principle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). If you just want an answer to your question without all the meddlesome "community" stuff you can find consultants on http://careers.stackoverflow.com